# How can I store temporary variables in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am wondering if TF has the capacity to temporarily store data during the training phase? Below is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def loss_function(values, a, b):
    N = values.shape[0]
    i = tf.constant(0)
    values_array = tf.get_variable(
        "values", values.shape, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(values), dtype=tf.float32) # The  temporary data solution in this example
    result = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)

    def body1(i):

        op2 = tf.assign(values_array[i, 0],
                        234.0) # Here is where it should be updated. The value being assigned is actually calculated from variable a and b.

        with tf.control_dependencies([op2]):
            return i + 1

    def condition1(i): return tf.less(i, N)
    i = tf.while_loop(condition1, body1, [i])

    op1 = tf.assign(values_array[0, 0],
                    9999.0) # Here is where it should be updated

    result = result + tf.reduce_mean(values_array) # The final cost is calculated based on the entire values_array
    with tf.control_dependencies([op1]):
        return result

# The parameters we want to calculate in the end
a = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], 0, 700), name='a')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -700, 700), name='b')

values = np.ones([2, 4], dtype=np.float32)

# cost function
cost_function = loss_function(values, a, b)

# training algorithm
optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(
    0.1, momentum=0.9).minimize(cost_function)

# initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# starting the session session
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

_, training_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost_function])

print tf.get_collection(
    tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope="values")[0].eval(session=sess)
```

Currently, what I get from the console is:

```
[[ 0.98750001  0.98750001  0.98750001  0.98750001]
     [ 0.98750001  0.98750001  0.98750001  0.98750001]]
```

What expected to get from this example is (if the temporary data can be printed out):

```
[[ 9999.0  1.0  1.0  1.0]
     [ 234.0  1.0  1.0  1.0]]
```

Overall, what I want is that the cost function calculates a temporary 2D array based on the input numpy 2D array and parameters a and b. Then, the final cost is calculated from the temporary 2D array. But I think using a TF variable as the temporary storage is probably not correct...

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop never runs because `i` is never used again. use `tf.control_dependencies` to make it run.

Also, you are adding the mean of values_array, when you seem to just want to add the array as-is. Get rid of `reduce_mean` to get your desired output.

`op1 = tf.assign(values_array[0, 0], 9999.0)` wasn't being done because there was no op in the following `control_dependencies` context. Move the op to the context to ensure that the assignment op is included in the graph.

```
def loss_function(values, a, b):
    N = values.shape[0]
    i = tf.constant(0)
    values_array = tf.get_variable(
        "values", values.shape, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(values), dtype=tf.float32, trainable=False)

    temp_values_array = tf.get_variable(
        "temp_values", values.shape, dtype=tf.float32)

    # copy previous values for calculations & gradients
    temp_values_array = tf.assign(temp_values_array, values_array)

    result = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)

    def body1(i):

        op2 = tf.assign(temp_values_array[i, 0],
                        234.0) # Here is where it should be updated. The value being assigned is actually calculated from variable a and b.

        with tf.control_dependencies([op2]):
            return [i+1]

    def condition1(i): return tf.less(i, N)

    i = tf.while_loop(condition1, body1, [i])

    with tf.control_dependencies([i]):
        op1 = tf.assign(temp_values_array[0, 0],
                    9999.0) # Here is where it should be updated

        with tf.control_dependencies([op1]):
            result = result + temp_values_array # The final cost is calculated based on the entire values_array

            # save the calculations for later
            op3 = tf.assign(values_array, temp_values_array)
            with tf.control_dependencies([op3]):
                return tf.identity(result)
```

Also, you are fetching `optimizer` so the non-assigned elements of your output are going to be smaller than you expect. Your results would be closer if you did:

```
training_cost = sess.run([cost_function])
_ = sess.run([optimizer])
```

This will ensure that you don't optimize before getting the results of `cost_function`

Comment: Thanks. It is very helpful. The final goal is to minimize the cost and get optimal parameters a and b by running the optimizer through iterations. In this way, I think the value of the temporary variable will still be affected?

Comment: If you add `trainable=False` to `tf.get_variable("values"...` then it won't change when the optimization is done.

Comment: Sounds great. But I get `ValueError(u'No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable \'a:0\' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable \'b:0\' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>"] and loss Tensor("Identity:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).',)` after adding the argument.

Comment: it's because there's nothing to train. `a` and `b` are trainable but don't contribute to cost_function, and also `values_array` is untrainable. If you want to test it anyway, comment out `# _ = sess.run([optimizer])`

Comment: An extra question: Since the final cost is designed to calculate from the untrainable temporary variable, and the temporary variable is calculated from the trainable parameter a and b, I constantly get the Error mentioned above. Any clue to solve this issue?

Comment: I edited my answer to allow gradients to pass thru the assignments. The trick is to do all of the calculations with a trainable variable that gets replaced by the one acting as memory. If it still doesn't work, you might want to post it as another question, since the problem is different.

Comment: I think this is the same as using a trainable variable directly. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry. After running your code, I am getting this expection: `ValueError('Sliced assignment is only supported for variables',)` on `op2 = tf.assign(temp_values_array[i, 0], 234.0)`.

Comment: I would copy the new code into a new question so it can receive more attention and have a fresh conversation